# push segue transition really choppy iOS App swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

I have looked at multiple stackoverflow posts and googled about it for hours, but can't figure out why transition is so choppy. I am not doing too much work on my main thread, and I am just using some functions to calculate numbers to display in the tableview, which I tried putting on a separate thread, but that didn't help either!

It's choppy when I run it on the simulator and my phone too.

https://recordit.co/S5I772t5t6

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the pushed view controller has clear background color, or a background color with alpha < 1. In my experience this might cause the push animation to look odd.

Comment: that was it, the background color was clear!! Thank you so much T-T I spent way too long on this haha